# Trying to generate Buttons with a loop, but Icon property causes problem

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, mxml

I'm trying to generate a button with the loop of an array, but I can't make the icon style and the stylename work :(

```
        for (var x:int = 0; x < smileys.length; x++ ) {
            var emoticon:Button = new Button();
            var label:String = smileys[x][0];
            emoticon.width = 24; emoticon.height = 24;
            emoticon.x = positionX; emoticon.y = 0;
            emoticon.styleName('buttonImg'); // doesn't work...
            emoticon.setStyle("icon", "@Embed(source='smileys/"+smileys[x][0]+".png')"); // doesn't work
            emoticonsGroup.addChild(emoticon);
            positionX+= 24;
        }
```

I also tried to insert this in the loop but it doesn't work neither :

```
        [Embed(source="smileys/"+smileys[x][0]+".png")] // fb doesn't like that
        var buttonIcon:Class;
        emoticon.setStyle("icon", buttonIcon);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put variables in an embedding since it's an instruction for the compiler, not a runtime resolution. Now, you can either

- create as many variables as smileys you have and then have N static embeddings
- create your own skin for a button which accepts an `Image` or a `Loader` and load dynamically the image inside the button
- preload an swf with all your images and use `emoticon.setStyle("icon", getDefinitionByName(smileys[x][0]))` where `smileys[x][0]` is the linkage name of the smiley in the Flash library.

Comment: Okay, well that appears to be quite long code, longer than the actual. 
I'm coming from HTML/PHP world, and used to use array to create fastly display elements so I tried to do the same procedure in ActionScript

Comment: It's basically a good idea, but Embed writes the image into the binary of the swf, the HTML behavior is more similar to `Loader`. You only have to create a `Sprite` object (which can have its `buttonMode` set to true) and `addChild` a `Loader` to it with the URL of the picture.